# Given two label fields inside an HorizontalFieldManager, how should I do to display the full text from second label without wrapping it?

Tags: java, blackberry, labelfield, horizontalfieldmanager

I have an HorizontalFieldManager with two labels inside.
The left label shows a description, and the right one shows
a money amount.

For me, it's more important to show the full text of the
second label. Problem is that if the first label is too long,
the second label will be wrapped. I want to avoid that, so
text from second label always is displayed. I also need to avoid
the wrapping over first label in that case, so text from that label
is trimmed and filled with dots.

This is how the HorizontalFieldManager looks:
[image]

And this is what I need to get:
[image]

How should I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create your `LabelField` with the `LabelField.ELLIPSIS` flag, it will truncate the field with `.` characters.  I would recommend that you use a custom `Manager` subclass (instead of `HorizontalFieldManager`) to decide what the proper width of your two `LabelFields` should be.  You can do this by asking what the proper width is of the dollar amount, given the current font.

Try this example:

```java
public class LabelAlignScreen extends MainScreen {

   private LabelField description;
   private LabelField balance;
   private static final int MARGIN = 8;  // used for x and y

   public LabelAlignScreen() {
      super(MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLL | MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);

      Manager row = new RowManager(Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
      description = new LabelField("This is a very looooooooooong description", 
            LabelField.ELLIPSIS);
      row.add(description);
      balance = new LabelField("1,500,000,000 USD");
      row.add(balance);
      add(row);
   }

   private class RowManager extends Manager {
      public RowManager(long flags) {
         super(flags);
      }

      protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
         // first, determine how much space the balance field needs
         int balanceWidth = balance.getFont().getAdvance(balance.getText());
         // description field gets leftover width, 
         //   minus a margin at left, center and right
         int descriptionWidth = width - balanceWidth - 3 * MARGIN;

         setPositionChild(description, MARGIN, MARGIN);
         layoutChild(description, descriptionWidth, description.getPreferredHeight());

         setPositionChild(balance, MARGIN + descriptionWidth + MARGIN, MARGIN);
         layoutChild(balance, balanceWidth, balance.getPreferredHeight());  

         setExtent(width, getPreferredHeight());
      }

      public int getPreferredHeight() {
         return Math.max(balance.getPreferredHeight(), description.getPreferredHeight()) + 2 * MARGIN;
      }

      public int getPreferredWidth() {
         return Display.getWidth();
      }
   }
}
```

*Note: you didn't specify whether the dollar/balance field should be a **fixed** width, or always just barely enough to fit the text.  I assumed that it should just barely fit the text, as I think that makes for a better layout in most cases.  Also, my code above uses a hardcoded `MARGIN` value for the space around all the fields.  You can adjust that if you like.*

### Results

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See that example :

```
class Test {
    public String StringShorter(String field, int maxsize) {
    //create a function that process the String you want to put in your field
    StringBuilder strb=new StringBuilder();
    // lets say you want your field to not more than 10 characters

        if(field.length()>=maxsize) {
            strb.append(field.substring(0,maxsize));
            strb.append("...");
        }
        return strb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test sl=new Test();
        System.out.println(sl.StringShorter("sdadasfdfsdfsdfsdfdsffdfs", 10)); 
        // define the maximum characters here it is defined to be maximum 10 characters
        }
    }
```

the output would be :

```
sdadasfdfs...
```